# Heroku's Django is not loading lity.css and lity.js

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I am trying to use this simple lightbox for embedding a video on my Django project. Locally with:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

it runs fine. However, once deployed to Heroku the app struggles to find the css and the js of lity, though it is located in the correct folder. Has anyone run into a similar problem?

The project is live here:
https://dry-depths-69493.herokuapp.com/

And the git-repo is here:
https://github.com/Datenrausch/heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code in github, I see that `... master/honoradar/static/honoradar/lity/` has no subfolder named `dist`, but your HTML looks for that subfolder.

Try changing these lines from `index.html` to the correct files (I'm not sure which are the correct ones)

```
<script src="{% static 'honoradar/lity/dist/lity.js'%}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/honoradar/lity/dist/lity.css">
```

or add a `dist` subfolder with the correct files.

Comment: also: any reason why the js has the `static` tag but the css doesn't?

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for pointing out such an obvious mistake. I do not know why but the dist folder is here locally but did not get pushed to github and hence also not to heroku. Fixed it for now by changing the references and the folder structure.